# Estoy intentando hacer un sistema de listas

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy intentando hacer un sistema de listas, con 2 columnas, fecha y nombre. Al darle a un `input`, se subirá a un array y pasará a almacenarse en el **localStorage**, y después en el `html` llama al **localStorage**. se vería algo así:
(no tiene más explicacion, abajo pondré relleno)

[insertar el array, que se une con 
 y hace espacios]

pero, primero no me deja usar `appendChild` y segundo en si no me deja
code:

```js
var unaCosa = ["unacosa1", "unacosa2", "etc"];
var cosaString = unaCosa.join("<br>");

localStorage.setItem("tal", cosaString);

var resultado = localStorage.getItem("tal")
var createP = document.createElement("P");
var productosResu = createP.innerHTML = resultado;

document.getElementById("ProdP").appendChild(productosResu);

function delItem (key) {
  localStorage.removeItem(key);
};
```

```html
                <input type="text" id="texto" placeholder="Introduzca el producto" maxlength="30">
                <select id="dia">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>11</option>
                    <option>12</option>
                    <option>13</option>
                    <option>14</option>
                    <option>15</option>
                    <option>16</option>
                    <option>17</option>
                    <option>18</option>
                    <option>19</option>
                    <option>20</option>
                    <option>21</option>
                    <option>22</option>
                    <option>23</option>
                    <option>24</option>
                    <option>25</option>
                    <option>26</option>
                    <option>27</option>
                    <option>28</option>
                    <option>29</option>
                    <option>30</option>
                    <option>31</option>
                </select>
                <select id="mes">
                    <option>Enero</option>
                    <option>Febrero</option>
                    <option>Marzo</option>
                    <option>Abril</option>
                    <option>Mayo</option>
                    <option>Junio</option>
                    <option>Julio</option>
                    <option>Agosto</option>
                    <option>Septiembre</option>
                    <option>Octubre</option>
                    <option>Noviembre</option>
                    <option>Diciembre</option>
                </select>
                <select id="any">
                    <option>2019</option>
                    <option>2020</option>
                    <option>2021</option>
                    <option>2022</option>
                    <option>2023</option>
                    <option>2024</option>
                    <option>2025</option>
                    <option>2026</option>
                    <option>2027</option>
                    <option>2028</option>
                    <option>2029</option>
                    <option>2030</option>
                    <option>2031</option>
                    <option>2032</option>
                    <option>2033</option>
                </select>
                <button id="boton">+</button>
            </div>
            <p id="ProdP">
            <!-- 1. No se como insertar el array aqui. lo probe pero no. -->
            </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si solo vas a insertar tus valores del array en el párrafo, usa `innerHTML` y te va a imprimir en forma de lista los valores que tengas en tu array cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
var unaCosa = ["unacosa1", "unacosa2", "etc"];
var cosaString = unaCosa.join("<br>");

localStorage.setItem("tal", cosaString);

var resultado = localStorage.getItem("tal")
var createP = document.createElement("P");
var productosResu = createP.innerHTML = resultado;

document.getElementById("ProdP").innerHTML = productosResu;
```

```html
<p id="ProdP"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.appendChild(element)` debe recibir como argumento un *element*. En tu caso el resultado de `document.createElement("P")`. Entonces el código debería ser así:

```
var unaCosa = ["unacosa1", "unacosa2", "etc"];
var cosaString = unaCosa.join("<br>");

localStorage.setItem("tal", cosaString);

var resultado = localStorage.getItem("tal")
var createP = document.createElement("P");
createP.innerHTML = resultado;

document.getElementById("ProdP").appendChild(createP);//<-- el elemento creado

function delItem (key) {
  localStorage.removeItem(key);
};
```

y aquí un ejemplo funcional https://jsfiddle.net/q4ta0d7n/